# Area enclosed by curves.

Tags: integration

Find the area enclosed by the curves:

$x=4-y^2$ and $x=y-2$

$-3 \le y \le 2$

$y-2 \le x \le 4-y^2$

My multiple integral:

$\int_{-3}^{3}( \int_{y-2}^{4-y^2}dx)dy$

Is this right?

Comment: Why not sketch the area?

Comment: Outer limits are not correct...

Answer (score 0):

> $x=4-y^2$ and $x=y-2$
>
> $-3 \le y \le 2$
>
> $y-2 \le x \le 4-y^2$

Yes, that is correct! A simple [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7Bx%3D4-y%5E2,x%3Dy-2%7D) is always useful.

Careful though:

> My multiple integral:
>
> $\int_{-3}^{\color{red}{3}}( \int_{y-2}^{4-y^2}dx)dy$

The upper limit for $y$ should be $2$ instead of $3$, as you probably calculated correctly above.

Comment: So the final answer is $ \int_{-3}^{2} (-y^2-y+6)dy=  \frac{125}{6} $ ?

Comment: Yes, that is [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%7B-3%7D%5E%7B2%7D+(int_%7By-2%7D%5E%7B4-y%5E2%7D+dx)+dy).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-3}^{2}( \int_{y-2}^{4-y^2}dx)dy$$

$$\int_{-3}^{2}6-\int_{-3}^{2}y^2-\int_{-3}^{2} y =30-{35\over3}+{5\over2}={180-70+15\over6}={125\over6}$$

[image]